# How to make a counter of people who have been invited to the server?

Tags: discord.js

Its my code

```
    var args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    var command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

if(command == "myinv"){

    var invs = (await message.member.guild.fetchInvites().then(invites => invites.findAll("memberCount"))).values()


    return message.channel.send(elo)

}
```

When i use command i got error like this:

```
(node:22680) DeprecationWarning: Collection#findAll: use Collection#filter instead
(node:22680) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Value must be specified.
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Discord collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) has no method `.findAll`, the one way to get count of invites uses, its 
get serverinvites, then filter this collection, because discord not guaranteed property of `invite.uses`, then you can reduce it for get a summ.

```js
var args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
var command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

if(command == "myinv"){
    let invites = message.member.guild.fetchInvites().then(invites => {
    let countInvites = invites.filter(invite => (invite.hasOwnProperty('uses'))).reduce((a, b) => {
        a.uses + b.uses
    }, 0)
        message.channel.send(`Total server invite uses: **${countInvites}**`)
    })
}
```